# What's the quickest, most easily repeatable way to die 100 times?

Tags: achievements, octodad-dadliest-catch

I'm trying to earn the achievement 'Number 100 Dad' in *Octodad: Dadliest Catch*:

[image: Achievement on Steam]

Dying 100 times is a lot of death, so I'd like to make it as quick and painless as possible.

What's the quickest, most easily repeatable way to die in Octodad: Dadliest Catch?

Comment: .....#clickbait

Comment: @OldBunny2800 You just summed up all Arqade HNQ in one hashtag. Nice!

Comment: @OldBunny2800 [You haven't seen anything yet...](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248277/can-i-marry-my-grandmother)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At the start of the last level, '*Hot Concessions'*, you must run and escape from the chef as he attempts to catch you:

[image: Running from the Chef]

[image: Being Caught]

As being caught is instant-death, and you will respawn into this situation without any user-interaction, this is the fastest and easiest place to die and work toward this achievement.