# Where to dowload a DDoS virus?

Tags: hacker-experience

I don't know where to find a DDoS virus can anyone help me?
When I am trying to download it from the download center it looks like this:[image]

Comment: I am assuming this is for a game, but you should clarify what a “DDoS virus” is. As someone unfamiliar with hacker experience, it looks like you are asking where to download a real virus

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Um, this is hardly the worst... here is one with [marrying your grandma](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248277/can-i-marry-my-grandmother).

Comment: @StevenVascellaro That is why I tried to edit the title, I guess it didn't go through. The title "Where to download a DDoS Virus?" scared me a little when I first saw it.

Comment: You're only scared because you have no idea what a DDoS actually is.  You don't need viruses to do a DDoS.  You can do it with legit, non-infected computers.  Just run **ping -t <host>** on more and more computers until the host stops responding.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, the Basic Warez is a virus that has not been executed.  You can download those.

However, the DDoS viruses further down, someone has already `Executed` them, so they're running and belongs to someone.

The download center don't usually stock DDoS viruses though.

If you follow the puzzle servers, one of the early ones will stock one.  However, people like to login and run it, so you check the server's software reset time, and download it before it gets executed.

Note:  DDoS leaves a lot of footprint of your server.  You will get attacked pretty quickly after DDoSing someone, so either pre-load an IP reset or just don't do it.