# How do I become a goat again after turning into a bag?

Tags: goat-simulator

I was walking around in the Goat Simulator: PayDay expansion when I came to a Bag Vendor with a platform to the left of it.  I stood on the platform and literally mutated into a bag (a loot bag in PayDay).

Now all I can do is hop around as a bag.  How do I change back into a Goat?

*Note: I am assuming I can just restart the game or level, but I have completed almost all of the missions (pranks) so I do not want to start over.  Opting to Respawn just put me back at the respawn area as a bag.*

Comment: Another fitting question for the HNQ list.

Comment: @Logarr, Goats are the new cats.

Comment: The question title out of context made me laugh inappropriately hard.

Comment: Where else in the world could we be able to witness such a question asked so seriously and such a serious answer to it?! Made my day

Comment: I take this game very seriously. There is nothing funny about a ragdolling goat. It's very serious. I'm not kidding.

Comment: @Logarr I think it's impossible to ask a question about this game that does **not** fit the HNQ list.

Comment: @Logarr What's the HNQ list?

Comment: @LarsH Hot Network Questions. It's the list of really active questions from the StackExchange network on the side of each site. Arqade tends to have hilarious titles when out of context. Like every Crusader Kings 2 question ever.

Comment: @Logarr Crusader Kings 2 are the best ones.  Here's one about [marrying your grandma](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248277/can-i-marry-my-grandmother)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

All of your unlocked mutators can be found and toggled on or off in the game menu, allowing you to turn on multiple mutators at once, or turn off unwanted ones.

Comment: Yep it was a mutator.  Thanks for the simple answer - I thought I had to go to a different platform to remove the bag or something.

Comment: Glad I could help